# adding loop with innerloop inside innerHTML

Tags: loops, innerhtml

I would like to create student cards for students who are looking for schools which match their needs best. For example.

*Winston likes to student Frontend and has basketball and drawing as his hobbies.*

A card should be created for his profile listing schools which match his needs from best to worst:

- Best schools (matching programme and all hobbies) should be listed in green.
- Second choices (schools matching what they want to study, but not offering all the hobbies).

**How do I loop through the students to make a list and have an innerloop which shows the schools in order from best to worst?**

I am hoping my final result to look like this: [example card](https://drive.google.com/file/d/11D5TRvH4p_paULB6jUwLSaellM7WFO_2/view?usp=sharing)

```
let students = [
  {
    firstName: "Winston",
    lastName: "Green",
    age: "29",
    hobbies: ["basketball", "drawing"],
    programme: "Frontend"
  },
  {
    firstName: "Cassandra",
    lastName: "White",
    age: "18",
    hobbies: ["chess", "gaming", "drawing"],
    programme: "Backend"
  }
];

let schools = [
  {
    name: "Fun School",
    activities: ["drawing", "chess", "football", "basketball", "gaming"],
    programmes: []
  },
  {
    name: "Data School",
    activities: ["drawing", "chess", "gaming"],
    programmes: [".NET", "Frontend"]
  },
  {
    name: "Makrosoft School",
    activities: ["football", "gaming"],
    programmes: ["Backend", ".NET"]
  },
  {
    name: "Boring School",
    activities: "No activities",
    programmes: ["Frontend", "Backend"]
  },
  {
    name: "Frontend School",
    activities: ["drawing", "basketball"],
    programmes: ["Frontend"]
  }
];
const studentsList = document.getElementById("studentsList");

const htmlString = students
  .map((student) => {
    return `
  <div class="card">
  <div class="card__inner">
    <div class="card__face card__face--front">
      <h2>${student.firstName} ${student.lastName}</h2>
      <h3>${student.programme}</h3>
      <h4>Age: ${student.age}</h4>
      ---
      <h5>schools which match with programme and has all the student's hobbies:</h5>
      // list with matching schools (first choices)
      <h5>school which match with programme and has some of the student's hobbies:</h5>
      // list with matching schools (second choices)
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
`;
  })
  .join("");
studentsList.innerHTML = htmlString;
```